# Which volume of TAOCP should I start with?

Tags: preference, taocp

I have decided to go through "The Art Of Computer Programming" series by Sir Donald Knuth.

Based on your experience, please suggest which volume would be a good one to start with, *as in an easier one* (relative to others) and also, please suggest your preferred order for reading subsequent volumes.

I am in no rush to learn it all, so *any type* of volume should be OK with me to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first volume of TAOCP contained this diagram:

[image: Flow chart for reading The Art of Computer Programming]

Comment: Right on! I starting reading the Volume 1 yesterday and I encountered the same diagram (I didn't see your answer by then).

Comment: my two cent worth advise would be to NOT start with 1st volume at all, start with something interesting and then go back and forth. For example. _Generating all the permutations_ if it sounds of interest to you.

Comment: I'm assuming that "begin new section" means to move on to the next section in order in that chapter.  I don't know what "*" means.

Comment: More detail to the flow chart can be found on page xiii [here](http://broiler.astrometry.net/~kilian/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming%20-%20Vol%201.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute first thing you should do is read the first few chapters from the first volume.  They go over basic stuff, including MIX [supposedly there's a new version with MMIX, though I havent seen it yet] which is the model Knuth uses throughout the series

I'm a math guy, so I found the second volume [dealing with "seminumerical" algorithms -- called so because Knuth felt that it wasnt strictly numerical] much more interesting than the sorting and searching stuff [V3]

Comment: Also, if you arent a math person at heart, avoid the HM problems